# How to use RAPIDS module and MetaTrader5 module in the same python project

Tags: wsl-2, windows-11, metatrader5, rapids

I want to use the RAPIDS and MetaTrader5 modules in the same project in a Windows 11 environment.

The RAPIDS module requires the use of WSL2 in Windows 11, and the MetaTrader5 module needs to be used in the pip environment in Windows.

So, these two modules cannot be used in the same project. Is there any way I can resolve this issue?

---

OS: windows 11

WSL2: Ubuntu 22.04

Python: 3.10

RAPIDS: 23.08

MetaTrader5: 5.0.45

Comment: If you're using WSL2, then you're effectively using Linux. So if MetaTrader5 works on Linux, it shouldn't (generally) matter if your OS is Windows.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel MetaTrader5 works on only Windows, It not works on Linux.

Comment: Then you can't use it from WSL2, and if you can only use RAPIDS from Linux (through WSL2), you can't combine them (at least not in one application).